# While fetch html content through "preg_match_all" function special char not display proper, how to resolve this?

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I'm fetch the html content using below code,

```
preg_match_all('/<div class="content">(.*?)<\/div>/s', $str, $matches);
echo $matches[1][0];
```

Content fetched correctly but some special char whit text not display properly like

`“response to what?”` display as â€œresponse to what?â€

`but it doesn’t` display as but it doesnâ€™t matter.
and some blanck space display as Â

how to resolve this issue..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have unicode issues, try adding this as the first line in your script :

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Answer (score 1):

first add this line in your code...(above)

```
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```